# AngularJs Redirect URL not passing Authorization header to server

Tags: angularjs, node.js, authentication, typescript

I am working on an AngularJs project and I am pretty new to web. What I am trying to achieve is simple login. I have implemented token base auth, on the server side(nodejs) and also in the client side.

Everything seems to work great. Except when i try to

> this.$window.location.href

When I click login, to test if my authentication is working properly, I have called an $http.get to an authorized end point it work perfectly. Then I make a call to nodejs(serve) to serve me a page on a given endpoint, which needs the authorization token header. But its not being sent.

```
  public loginClick = () => {
        this.authService.login(this.user).then(msg => {
            console.log("success");
            this.$http.get(Config.apiEndpoint().url + '/memberinfo').then(result => { 

                console.log(result.data); //<== this works
                var landingUrl = "http://" + this.$window.location.host + "/dashboard/";
                this.$window.location.href = landingUrl; //<== this does not works
            });

        }, errMsg => {
            console.log("failes");
        });

    }
```

nodejs code

```
app.get('/', moduleRoutes.root);
app.get('/dashboard/', moduleRoutes.root);

export function root(req: express.Request, res: express.Response) {
    if (authorization.isAuthorized(req, res)) {
        res.sendfile('./public/views/index.html');
    } else {
        res.sendfile('./public/views/login.html');
    }
};
```

Comment: try using $location instead of .$window.location.href

Comment: You don't seem to be telling $http to send any extra headers. You can have a look at the documentation for setting headers here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http/#setting-http-headers

Comment: Also, you seem to be sending back an entire page.. you shouldn't do that with the $http service.. it's more of a thing you can solve with a router. :)

Comment: using $location i will get #/dashboard and will not call my endpoint

Comment: extra headers are being added when I use $http.get but not $window.location.href

Comment: Ofcourse not, $http is an angular utility, location.href is just a browser function, there is nothing in angular telling it to put those headers there. However if what you want to achieve is navigation, have a look at routing in angularjs. There is a small tutorial for router based auth here: https://coderwall.com/p/f6brkg/angularjs-access-control-and-authentication

Comment: you shouldn't be using $window.location.href... anyway dear... angular has a lot more and easy wys

Answer (score -1):

**You should use $location like this :**

```
 public loginClick = () => {
        this.authService.login(this.user).then(msg => {
            console.log("success");
            this.$http.get(Config.apiEndpoint().url + '/memberinfo').then(result => { 

                console.log(result.data);
                $location.path('/dashboard');
            });

        }, errMsg => {
            console.log("failes");
        });

    }
```

**Thanks & Cheers**